# Como criar um loop que transforme colunas em variáveis e devolva shapiro.test ao final?

Tags: r

Tenho vários arquivos .csv com um número elevado de colunas. Gostaria de otimizar o trabalho criando uma função que leia as colunas e retorne o resultado do teste de normalidade (*shapiro.test*) de cada uma delas.

```
    data <- read.csv2("C:/Users/z/Desktop/CSVFOREST_WB.csv")

tnorm <- function(x){
  for (a in x) {
    a = x[[1,]]
    return(shapiro.test(a))

}  

                     }
tnorm(data)
```

O código, claro, retorna erro. O que posso fazer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

O `R` não é uma linguagem muito boa para utilizar loops como `for` e `while`. Dependendo do número de replicações e da sua complexidade, a execução pode vir a ficar muito lenta.

Entretanto, ele possui algumas funções que facilitam o trabalho de quem quer repetir muitas vezes o mesmo cálculo. Algumas destas funções estão na família `*apply`, como `apply`, `sapply` e `lapply`.

Tome, por exemplo, o conjunto de dados abaixo. Ele possui 5 colunas, cada uma com 100 observações. Todas possuem distribuição normal com média 0 e desvio padrão 1:

```
n <- 100 # tamanho amostral
r <- 5   # quantidade de amostras

dados <- data.frame(matrix(rnorm(n*r, mean=0, sd=1), ncol=5))
```

Se eu quiser testar a normalidade de cada uma das colunas deste conjunto de dados, basta rodar

```
apply(dados, 2, shapiro.test)
```

em que

- `dados`: é o mu conjunto de dados
- `2`: indica que vou aplicar uma função em cada coluna de `dados`. Se eu tivesse colocado `1`, esta função seria aplicada nas linhas de `dados`
- `shapiro.test`: indica a função que vou aplicar a cada coluna (`2` no item acima) de `dados`

O resultado obtido é o seguinte:

```
$X1

    Shapiro-Wilk normality test

data:  newX[, i]
W = 0.98757, p-value = 0.4773


$X2

    Shapiro-Wilk normality test

data:  newX[, i]
W = 0.98678, p-value = 0.4228


$X3

    Shapiro-Wilk normality test

data:  newX[, i]
W = 0.95448, p-value = 0.001656


$X4

    Shapiro-Wilk normality test

data:  newX[, i]
W = 0.98871, p-value = 0.5622


$X5

    Shapiro-Wilk normality test

data:  newX[, i]
W = 0.98234, p-value = 0.2015
```

Veja que em cada coluna foi aplicado o teste de Shapiro-Wilk e obtivemos o valor da estatística e do p-valor associado a ela.